# Should I convert my inline script so I can put it into an external .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery, and I have been using the SnapScroll jQuery plugin by koga73 (https://github.com/koga73/SnapScroll) in my webpage.

It has requested me to use the inline script:

```
<script> 
var snapScroll = $("header, section, footer").SnapScroll({
hashes:true }); console.log(snapScroll);

$("header").on(snapScroll.eventChangeActive, function(evt, newActive){
console.log(evt, newActive);
});

$(document).on(snapScroll.eventChangeVisible, function(evt, visibleList){
console.log(evt, visibleList.data);
});
</script>
```

It's been working fine, but I was just wondering is it worth moving it into an external .js file, and if so, how do I convert the code to work in an external .js file?

My external js file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="web/js/init.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to put all of your JavaScript in external files - inline is nice for debugging and developing, but when you go into production, always an external file that has been minified and compressed - though, you can worry about the last two later.

If you put that code in a file you want to place that code like this...
..and lose the script tags

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.

$(document).ready(function() {
    var snapScroll = $("header, section, footer").SnapScroll({
    hashes:true }); console.log(snapScroll);

    $("header").on(snapScroll.eventChangeActive, function(evt, newActive){
        console.log(evt, newActive);
    });

    $(document).on(snapScroll.eventChangeVisible, function(evt, visibleList){
        console.log(evt, visibleList.data);
    });
});

//OR
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()

$(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Then, insert your external script link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could just paste the lines inside tag to js file.
You don't need script tag inside js file.
Thats it.
It is really your preference whether you put the codes inline or in external js file.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense. I wasn't fully aware of how it worked. Thank-you!